# Corona SDK: Error: "attempt to index field "?" a nil value", but only when I am on a certain scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk, null, lua-table, corona-storyboard

So I am making a game which has a lot of values to save. I used a module by Rob Miracle with makes it easy to save and load tables to do this with two tables. One is named "gamestuff" and the other is named "leveltries".

In one scene I declare the values of these tables (only if they haven't been saved before)

```
gamestuff.level = 1
        gamestuff.sound = true
        gamestuff.name = "user"
        gamestuff.highscore = 0
        gamestuff.lastscore = 0
        gamestuff.volume = 0.5
        gamestuff.lastlevel = 1
        gamestuff.won = false
        gamestuff.bouncesleft = 0

        local leveltries = {
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},
            {tries =0, wins = 0, fails = 0, retries = 0, bouncesleft = 0, bestbounces = 0, score = 0},


        }
        loadsave.saveTable(leveltries, "leveltries.json")
    loadsave.saveTable(gamestuff, "gamestuff.json")
```

This works fine except for when I try to go to a restart level scene and a win scene after the first level.

But it confuses me because in level one I try

```
        print("Fails: "..leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel].fails)
```

and it works

But when I try it in the restarter scene, it doesn't:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()
local loadsave = require("loadsave")

local gamestuff = {}
local leveltries = {}
local options =
{
    effect = "fade",
    time = 400
}

local function loader()
    gamestuff = loadsave.loadTable("gamestuff.json")
    leveltries = loadsave.loadTable("leveltries.json")
    print("loaded")
end

local function save()
    loadsave.saveTable(gamestuff, "gamestuff.json")
    loadsave.saveTable(leveltries, "leveltries.json")
end

function scene:createScene(event)

    gamestuff = {}
    leveltries = {}
end

function scene:enterScene(event)

    loader()
    print("Fails"..leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel].fails) --says the error is here
    local a = leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel].fails + 1
    leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel].fails = a
    timer.performWithDelay( 50, function()
        save()
        storyboard.gotoScene("level"..tostring(gamestuff.lastlevel), options)
    end, 1 )

end

function scene:exitScene(event)
    local group = self.view
    storyboard.removeScene("restarter")

end

function scene:destroyScene(event)
    gamestuff = nil
    leveltries = nil
    options  = nil
end
scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


return scene
```

Can anyone tell my why the code above doesn't work?

Could it be that I don't properly remove the "gamestuff" and "leveltries" in level1?

I tried to put some prints in. In the level 1 scene:

Everything works:

```
print(gamestuff.lastlevel)

print(leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel].fails)

print(leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel])
```

However in the restarter scene, only:

```
print(gamestuff.lastlevel) --which prints 1 and is right
```

works

print(leveltries[gamestuff.lastlevel]), in the restarter scene prints nil

I don't know how this is possible. I load the same tables in the same way at the same time in both scenes and used them in the same way.

Could it be that I am removing the tables incorrectly?

In scene one these are my exitScene and removeScene:

```
function scene:exitScene(event)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("touch", shoot)
    menub:removeEventListener("touch", gotomenu)
    restartb:removeEventListener("touch", restart)
    goal:removeEventListener("collision", win)
    ball:removeEventListener("collision", hit)
    ball:removeEventListener("collision", grow)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", twinkle)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", redraw)
end

function scene:didExitScene(event)
    --storyboard.removeScene("level1")
end

function scene:destroyScene(event)
    bg:removeSelf()
    ball:removeSelf()
    goal:removeSelf()
    topwall:removeSelf()
    bottomwall:removeSelf()
    rightwall:removeSelf()
    leftwall:removeSelf()
    menub:removeSelf()
    bounces = nil
    bouncestext:removeSelf()
    taps = nil
    restartb:removeSelf()
    tuttext:removeSelf()
    gamestuff = nil

    bg = nil
    ball = nil
    goal = nil
    topwall = nil
    bottomwall = nil
    rightwall = nil
    leftwall = nil
    menub = nil
    bouncestext = nil
    restartb = nil
    tuttext = nil
    options = nil
    trailprops = nil
    for i = 1, 3 do
        wallColor[i] = nil
    end


end

scene:addEventListener("createScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("didExitScene", scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene", scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is , you are declaring the gamestuff and leveltries array at the beginning of the scene. Then y do u again declare it in the create scene. You are again overriding the same array. I think it doesnt make any sense. Remove the array which is declared in the create scene and try .